# how to query two databases in a single query in marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am replicating data from one topology to another (say data of topology 1 is in DB1 and data of topology 2 is in DB 2) and I want to perform a check on both the databases in a single query to check whether all the files are same or not either by checking their Uris or Hash values. Is that possible?

Comment: show us what you have done.

Answer (score 3):

A check using hash performs well only when you calculate the hash upfront, and store that inside the document or in its properties. But a check based on uris is pretty straight-forward. The following solution doesn't scale endlessly, but should work well up to a few million uris. Just copy-paste it in QConsole, and run it against the database of your choice, and change the `$other-db-name` value to the name of the database to compare against:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $other-db-name := "OtherDocuments"
return
xdmp:eval(
  '
    xquery version "1.0-ml";

    declare variable $uris as map:map external;

    "In other, but not here:",
    map:keys(cts:uris((), "map") - $uris),

    "Here, but not in other:",
    map:keys($uris - cts:uris((), "map"))
  ',
  (
    xs:QName("uris"), cts:uris((), "map")
  ),
  <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
    <database>{xdmp:database($other-db-name)}</database>
  </options>
)
```

HTH!

Comment: Another option is to run "cts:uris()" in each database (the results are automatically sorted), put the outputs into two files, and then do a diff from the command line.

Comment: thanks for the solution Wayne.. could you please help me on performing check using hash values... sometimes the case is that a Uri might vary a bit  for a document but the content is same .. so in that case i believe hash  check would be a better solution..